# How to add lib_lightgbm.dll to exe when using pyinstaller to freeze python code

Tags: python, pyinstaller, lightgbm

I am creating a single-file executable of a python code that imports Microsoft's LightGBM. I used the following command to create the exe:

```
pyinstaller -F --hidden-import numpy.core._dtype_ctypes pro.py
```

After creating the exe and running it, the following error occurs:

```
Exception: Cannot find lightgbm library file in following paths:
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI61682\lightgbm\lib_lightgbm.dll
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\lib_lightgbm.dll
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI61682\lightgbm\compile\lib_lightgbm.dll
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI61682\compile\lib_lightgbm.dll
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\lib\lib_lightgbm.dll
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI61682\compile\Release\lib_lightgbm.dll
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI61682\compile\windows\x64\DLL\lib_lightgbm.dll
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\Release\lib_lightgbm.dll
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\windows\x64\DLL\lib_lightgbm.dll
[6352] Failed to execute script pro
```

I tried adding `lib_lightgbm.dll` using the option :

`--add-data lib_lightgbm.dll;\compile`

This resolves the error on the machine that lightgbm is installed, but on other machines, it gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyiboot01_bootstrap.py", line 149, in __init__
  File "ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pro.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\...\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
  File "site-packages\lightgbm\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\...\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
  File "site-packages\lightgbm\basic.py", line 34, in <module>
  File "site-packages\lightgbm\basic.py", line 29, in _load_lib
  File "ctypes\__init__.py", line 426, in LoadLibrary
  File "site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyiboot01_bootstrap.py", line 151, in __init__
__main__.PyInstallerImportError: Failed to load dynlib/dll 'C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI7562\\lightgbm\\../compile\\lib_lightgbm.dll'. Most probably this dynlib/dll was not found when the application was frozen.
[4060] Failed to execute script pro
```

Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

Comment: adding dll files separately will not solve your problem. Try to collect all lightgbm data files in a hook. That would make more sense to pyinstaller.